# Highchart-ng border does not display

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've a chart for which I'm not able to display the border.

My code that sets the relevant properties:

```
<highchart id='chart1id'
    class='span8'
    style='height:300px'
    chart.borderColor='#FFFFFF' 
    chart.borderWidth='2' 
    chart.shadow='true'
    title.text= '{{selectedProduct}}' 
    series=':filtered_data'
    series.type='column'
    xaxis.type='category'
    convert=':c'
    legend.enabled='false'
    tooltip.valueDecimals='0'
    tooltip.valuePrefix='$'
></highchart>
```

Everything else works fine with the above code, except the border. Is there something else that I need to do? I asked the same question on Highchart forum and got no replies, so I'm hoping somebody here could help me.

Comment: it would help to see a live demo.. with the code you gave it is hard to help..

Comment: It looks like authors of this wrapper for angular, not catch all parameters. So I advice to contact with them.